# Desperate to find the name of 1980's "Twilight Zone" type show with "Time People"

Tags: story-identification, tv, the-twilight-zone, the-outer-limits

In this episode there are "Time People" who move in a slightly different dimension. We see them as a slow-moving blur... they hide your keys, move stuff so you can't find it, and love to cause gremlin like disruption in people's homes.

My family always blamed the "Time People" when ever we couldn't find something.  I'd guess it was around 1981.  I've searched all twilight zone, outer limits, amazing stories, but can't find anything about this! I'd really like to find it.  It was really creepy too!

Thanks!

Comment: Is the Vicpylon answer the episode or story you're looking for? It definitely fits, but I remember another one that was very different. It was much more focused on the "gremlin like" aspect without those incidents being accidents; and they weren't exactly "Time People", IIRC.

Answer (score 10):

There is a [*Twilight Zone* episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9XFRfeGBVI), "A Matter of Minutes" (from the somewhat obscure 1985 remake), that contains elements of your question. Though I do not remember the term "time people" they do reference losing keys, time travel and strange, faceless workers that might be mistaken for gremlins.

Comment: I remember this episode. Also, the fact that it didn't make any sense. If time is constructed frame by frame by some behind the scenes workers, does that mean some secondary set of workers is constructing the time that was passing during the construction phase?

Comment: My wife and I loved that episode. Whenever we can't find something, we joke that "the blue guys must have done it".

Answer (score 5):

- A matter of minutes.  When this happens to us we blame "the time guys".

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Some elaboration, such as explaining how this is a match in text rather than via a link, would improve this answer. Perhaps a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) would be helpful.