# Book where people are continually slipping between "close" parallel alternate worlds/paratime without realizing it?

Tags: story-identification, books, parallel-universe, alternate-history

Only clear recollection from the book is an example along the lines of:

Experience: *I know I put my keys on the table next to the door, but when I went back they weren't there. Looked all around the house, happened to pass by that table again - and there they were.*

Reason: *the person had slipped into a near-identical parallel-ity in which the keys had not been left on the table, and then slipped back again into the previous reality - or at least into another one which had the keys on the table.*

Perhaps a person or a team became aware of this, and some story took off from there.

Almost certainly 1985-2005-ish. English. Read in USA. Probably a stand-alone novel. Almost certainly more sci-fi than fantasy. Thought it sounded like a James P Hogan, but couldn't find one like it among the paperbacks at hand here. And - at least with the search terms tried - couldn't find a match by a web search.

Comment: There is a part of me that wants to say we've had this before, but I think it involved an agency, or entities, who would do things like move keys to influence history, like in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107867/desperate-to-find-the-name-of-1980s-twilight-zone-type-show-with-time-peopl

Comment: Interesting. That's one Twilight Zone I didn't recall at all.  In  the question posted, just used lost keys as an example, as do not recall specific object(s) mentioned in the book.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots moving an object on a shelf to change history is referenced here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110430/28516 but I don't think it is the work asked about here.

Comment: There *is* a James P. Hogan novel with a similar example: it's *Mission to Minerva*, the fifth book of the *Giants* series.

Comment: This is also a theme in _Finity_ by John Barnes.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions. *Finity* was very close - slipping without realizing, and the description of entwined universes (more "near" => more similar). However that explanation is pretty far into the story line after the action started, and rather than continual natural slipping, switching required association with a plot-device. *Mission to Minerva* also required an active device, but at one point a comment - never revisited - on minor discontinuities after "close" switches noted the experience could not be said to be totally unfamiliar.

Comment: [H. Beam Piper's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._Beam_Piper) *Paratime* stories mention people accidentally switching worlds.  [*He Walked Around the Horses*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_Walked_Around_the_Horses) is an example.  I don't think that's the story you are looking for, though, since people tend to stay in the alternative worlds - it is hard to accidentally switch worlds and nearly impossible to intentionally switch back.

Comment: [A. Bertram Chandler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._Bertram_Chandler) wrote some stories involving inadvertent travel between parallel worlds, but not in such minor ways.

Comment: The bit about the keys sounds very familiar.  I've read something with almost the same phrasing, but I can't put a name to the story or the author.  I want to say the same (or a related story in the same series) compared parallel worlds to pages in a book, where the content of one page may be very similar to adjacent pages or wildly different.

Comment: Hogan's "Paths to Elsewhere" has some similarities to the OPs question, as does "The Infinitive of Go" by John Brunner, but I don't think either hit the bulls eye.  (In the latter work, dimensional crossing occurs, but as a side effect of experiments with a Trek-like transporter device.)

Comment: Agree not Piper, which except for rare exception, like that story, required a Conveyor for movement. Chandler and Brunner are new to me, so something to look for...

Answer (score 3):

Possibly [Worlds of the Imperium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worlds_of_the_Imperium) by Keith Laumer.

The plot involves parallel worlds.  The protagonist is recruited to assassinate and replace his double on another world, where he is a ruthless dictator.   Does that sound familiar?

Here's a part that is similar to what you recall.

> Winter went on talking while I tried to assemble his fragmentary information into a coherent picture. A vast spider web of lines, each one a complete universe, each minutely different from all the others;
> ...
> "As to the very close lines, theory now seems to indicate that there is no actual physical separation between lines; those microscopically close to one another actually merge or blend. It's difficult to explain. One actually wanders from one to another, at random, you know.
> ....
> "So we're all shifting from one universe to another all the time without knowing it," I said skeptically.
>
> "Not necessarily all of us, not all the time," Winter said. "But emotional stress seems to have the effect of displacing one. Of course with the relative positions of two grains of sand, or even of two atoms within a grain of sand being the only difference between two adjacent lines, you'd not be likely to notice. But at times greater slips occur with most individuals. Perhaps you yourself have noticed some tiny discrepancy at one time or another; some article apparently moved or lost; some sudden change in the character of someone you know; false recollections of past events. The universe isn't all as rigid as one might like to believe."

[You can read the whole novel for free on Project Gutenberg.](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/65792)

If correct it's a duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254977/novel-with-a-hand-held-kinetic-gas-weapon/254980#254980) and [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/265136/book-involving-a-metaverse-of-many-parallel-worlds-a-section-of-which-is-known/265137#265137).

Comment: Now that is intriguing. Have a Baen paperback somewhere, but had summarily dismissed WotI, because remembered the protagonist was practically kidnapped off the street and taken "away" in a vehicle. Did not think of an in-story explanatory passage. Will re-read when get the chance. -OP

Answer (score 2):

John Barnes' [Finity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0312861184) might fit the bill.  In it, proximity to quantum computers cause people to switch between alternate universes, often without realizing it.  This [review](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/books/99/03/28/reviews/990328.28scifit.html) discusses it

> Lyle Peripart, an American expatriate who teaches astronomy in
> 21st-century New Zealand, takes for granted that his world was shaped
> by the triumph of Hitler's nuclear-armed forces over Allied resistance
> in the 1940's. Then he learns from a Delphic billionaire named
> Geoffrey Iphwin that widespread use of quantum-based computer chips is
> breaking down the barriers between the Many Worlds, so that calling on
> a cell phone or taking a ride in an automated taxi can catapult you
> into a reality with a radically different past.
>
> Peripart joins a group of adventurers out to discover why, in all the
> worlds they visit, there is no sign of life from the North American
> territory of the former United States. The cast of characters, who
> change in subtle and not so subtle ways as their pasts mutate, are
> engaging enough to hold our attention; along with the pathos and
> puzzlement inherent in their situation, they manage to find humor and
> several varieties of love before the narrative reaches as much of a
> conclusion as is possible in the endlessly malleable universe they
> inhabit.

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t Larry Niven’s “All the Myriad Ways,” is it?  It’s been a while since I read it, and I can’t find my copy to check, sorry.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should add details to show how it matches the question.

Comment: Thanks to the Internet Archive, you can read Niven's "All the Myriad Ways" here: https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v27n03_1968-10/page/n31/mode/2up But maybe the Niven parallel-worlds story you're thinking of is "For a Foggy Night" (from Niven's **collection** titled *All the Myriad Ways*) which you can read here: https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v041n01_1971-07_PDF/page/n65/mode/2up I don't think either of these is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks, just re-read it. No keys involved. Parallel worlds have recently been discovered, and protagonist — a policeman baffled by the sudden flood of senseless murders and suicides—realizes that certain people who get the concept — that for every decision they make there is another world in which they decide differently— become so conscious of the randomness/possibilities/ meaninglessness of their own choices that they start imagining themselves choosing any and all of their options… and then, choosing their next action randomly. No surprise, it does not end well for him.